# Colorscheme broken after upgrading to nvim v0.8.0, why did t_Co change?

Tags: neovim, color-scheme

Today I've upgraded from neovim 0.7.2 to 0.8.0 and my color scheme broke. It seems that some of the colors are okay and some of them are not.

I'm using this color scheme:
https://github.com/arzg/vim-colors-xcode/blob/master/colors/xcodelighthc.vim

here is output of the `:highlight` command:

[image]

The strange thing is that I have this color for example defined in my color scheme that I'm using:

`hi Pmenu guifg=#000000 guibg=#f4f4f4 gui=NONE cterm=NONE`

but the highlight command shows that

`Pmenu          xxx ctermfg=0 ctermbg=225 guibg=LightMagenta`

`guibg=#f4f4f4` vs `guibg=LightMagenta`

I've checked the changelog for breaking changes regarding colorscheme but I found nothing.

It seems that this weird behaviour is caused by this if statement

```
let s:t_Co = exists('&t_Co') && !empty(&t_Co) && &t_Co > 1 ? &t_Co : 2
if s:t_Co >= 256
```

Line: https://github.com/arzg/vim-colors-xcode/blob/master/colors/xcodelighthc.vim#L372

After the update `s:t_Co >= 256` evaluates to false and because of that it's not applying the colors correctly.

Comment: I'm seeing the same with fzf, updating from 0.6 and 0.7.2 to 0.8 seems to break it. Did you get any further with this issue?

Comment: @UltimateHawk I've commented out this line https://github.com/arzg/vim-colors-xcode/blob/master/colors/xcodelighthc.vim#L372 and it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

`git bisect` told me that neovim broke backward compatibility for `exists('&t_Co')` in [PR #20375](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/20375). After that commit was merged, the return value of `exists('&t_Co')` changed from 1 to 0, and even [built-in color schemes were also affected](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/20602).

Edit: I've reported the issue at [#21499](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/21499), and it is now fixed in nightly builds and the upcoming 0.8.2 release.